# jQuery show and hide events issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have some html elements with following structure.

```
<input class="test" />
<div class="test"></div>

<input class="test" />
<div class="test"></div>

<input class="test" />
<div class="test"></div>

<input class="test" />
<div class="test"></div>
```

Clicking on any input should .show its adjacent `<div>`

But it does trigger all divs

I want to make it that when I click on any Input field, only its adjacent `<div>` will be set to show and all others hide.

The jQuery code that I have so far is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('body').on('click', '.test', function () {
                $(this).fadeIn('medium').siblings("div").hide();
        });

    });     

</script>
```

Comment: you're selecting the whole class, it applies to all elements. Try closest(), might work. Btw, couldn't you use some more classes? You're deliberately complicating things..

Comment: Or even you can use next() also.

Comment: I am not a PRO in jQuery that's why my code looks horrible :) 
Where should I apply closest() ?

Comment: `.closest()` isn't applicable to your html structure because it starts at the current element and goes up through its ancestors, whereas your elements are all siblings. Use `.next()`.

Comment: Note that `$(this).fadeIn('medium')` doesn't really make much sense in your click handler: if the element needs to fade *in* it must currently be invisible, in which case how could a user click it?

Comment: Great. Thanks everyone. I am trying the changes as you people have recommended.  Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the call to `.siblings('div')` will apply to EVERY div since every element in your supplied HTML is on the same level.

If you don't want to change this structure, use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('body').on('click', '.test', function () {
            $(this).fadeIn('medium').next("div").hide();
    });

});     

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.siblings()` affect every div under the input box in the context so use `.next()` in jquery

```
$('body').on('click', '.test', function () {
       $("div.test").hide();    
       $(this).fadeIn('medium').next("div").show();

 });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rc3a30ry/)

Answer (score 0):

because you have all div with same class "test", sibiling is affecting all of this divs with class "test"

```
$('body').on('click', '.test', function () {
 $("div.test").hide();
 $(this).fadeIn('medium').next("div").show();  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rwjzfhLy/